# How to display HTML report in jenkins,If output folder contains Timestamp

Tags: selenium, jenkins, html-reports-jenkins

"C:\Jenkins_home\workspace\Test\TestResults\2019_06_24_03_13_44_PM\index.html"
In this above path my index.html is present but one folder completely depends on time timestamp.
So how can i display index.html in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

If you are using build artifacts to archive the results of tests and the files of the older runs would be deleted before each run, entering `TestResults/**/index.html` in the Files to archive field will help.

Comment: what if history older runs need to be maintained?